# How can I draw a vector diagram that illustrates polar and rectangular coordinates using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I was wondering how I can modify the code below so that I get this picture. I'm trying to put together different concepts with the angles, arrows and elements in the diagonal. Any help is very much appreciated.

[image: Polar and rectangular coordinates.]

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}  
   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
          \coordinate (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
          \coordinate (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
          \coordinate (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
          \draw (A) -- node[below] {$E_{k}$} (B) -- node[right] {$f_{k}$} (C) -- node[below] {$e_{k}$} (A);
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{figure}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Different coordinate systems are describe in TikZ manual, in paragraph *13 Specifying Coordinates (p129)*. For example, polar coordinates you can define as `(<angle>: distance)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short exercise from geometry and drawing with TikZ :-) :

```
    \documentclass[tikz,
                    border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, quotes}

    \begin{document}
      \centering
    % added labels of vertex
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \coordinate[label=below  left:A] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \coordinate[label=below right:C] (C) at ( 1.5cm,-1.0cm);
    \coordinate[label=above right:B] (B) at ( 1.5cm, 1.0cm);
    \draw[-Stealth]  (A) edge ["$E_{k}$" '] (B) 
                     (A) edge ["$f_{k}$" '] (C) 
                     (C)  to  ["$e_{k}$" '] (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    % slightly improved your MWE, by use package "quotes" 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \coordinate[label=below  left:A] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \coordinate[label=below right:C] (C) at ( 1.5cm,-1.0cm);
    \coordinate[label=above right:B] (B) at ( 1.5cm, 1.0cm);
    \draw[-Stealth]  (A) edge ["$E_{k}$",sloped] (B)
                     (A) edge ["$f_{k}$" '] (C)
                     (C)  to  ["$e_{k}$" '] (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    % coordinates and vectors determined by polar coordinates
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \coordinate[label=below  left:A] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \draw[-Stealth]  
        (A) to ["$E_{k}$",sloped] ++ ({atan(2/3)}:{sqrt(4+9)}) coordinate[label=above right:B] (B);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (A) to ["$f_{k}$" ']      ++ (0:3)           coordinate[label=below right:C] (C);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (C) to ["$e_{k}$" ']      ++ (90:2);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    % added angle label by help of package "angle"
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \coordinate[label=below  left:A] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (A) to ["$E_{k}$",sloped] ++ ({atan(2/3)}:{sqrt(4+9)})  coordinate[label=above right:B] (B);
    \draw[-Stealth] 
        (A) to ["$f_{k}$" ']      ++ (0:3)                      coordinate[label=below right:C] (C);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (C) to ["$e_{k}$" ']      ++ (90:2);
    \pic ["$\angle\theta_i$", draw, angle radius = 12mm, angle eccentricity=1.3]     
        {angle = C--A--B};
        \end{tikzpicture}

     % added measure of magnitude
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \coordinate[label=below  left:A] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
    % vector from A in direction of angle "atan(2/3)" (arcus tangens" 
    % and magnitude "sgrt(2^2+2^2)" (square root)
    % end of vector determine coordinate B, which is labeled with "B" north east from it (above right)
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (A) to ["$\hat{V}_i$" '] ++ ({atan(2/3)}:{sqrt(4+9)})  coordinate[label=above right:B] (B);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (A) to ["$f_{k}$" ']     ++ (0:3)                      coordinate[label=below right:C] (C);
    \draw[-Stealth]
        (C) to ["$e_{k}$" ']     ++ (90:2);
    % angle
    % drawn with syntax provided by package "angles", 
    % angles eccentricity determine label position
    % B--A--C is outer angle, C--A--B inner (sharp) angle
    \pic ["$\angle\theta_i$", draw, angle radius = 12mm, angle eccentricity=1.3]
        {angle = C--A--B};
    % magnitude
    % starting point of magnitude measure is determined by perpendicular distance of 3mm
    % from coordinate A calculated by "($(A)!3mm!90:(B)$)";
    % end point is determined with adding of vector magnitude and angle: "({atan(2/3)}:{sqrt(4+9)})"

\draw[{Bar[width=3.4mm]Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[]Bar[width=3.4mm]}]
        ($(A)!3mm!90:(B)$) to ["$\vert\hat{V}_i\vert$",sloped] + ({atan(2/3)}:{sqrt(4+9)});          
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Image below are from example 1, 2--3, 4 and 5 examples in MWE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, @Zarko. You nailed it. Looks great. I was just wondering how to add the diagonal rule above Ek with the magnitude.

Comment: Well, I will add it soon. For it the library `calc` is necessary.

Comment: Amazing, @Zarko. I wish I could go to the same TikZ school that you attended - the code is simply cryptic if we have no understanding of the underlying logic. Thank you very much, once again.

Comment: @LeonardoMartins, I add some comments to code of the last example, Hopefully they will help to understand, what some commands and macros do in code.

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned in your comment that the `TikZ` solution seems cryptic, I thought I'd give you an `Asymptote` solution.  The `Asymptote` language has many commonalities with `C++`, making it much less cryptic for me.

```
include markers; // provides the markangle function

unitsize(2cm);

// define vertices
pair A = (-1.5,-1.0);
pair B = ( 1.5,-1.0);
pair C = ( 1.5, 1.0);

// draw and label triangle sides
draw(Label("$e_i$"), A--B, Arrow(HookHead));
draw(Label("$\hat{V}_i$"), A--C, Arrow(HookHead));
draw(Label("$f_i$"), B--C, Arrow(HookHead));

// define, draw, and label offset hypotenuse
real pathAngle = degrees(C-A);
path offsetPath = shift(rotate(pathAngle)*(0,0.2))*(A--C);
draw(Label(rotate(pathAngle)*"$\left|\hat{V}_i\right|$"), offsetPath, NW, Bars);

// draw and label the angle
markangle("$\angle\theta_i$", 50.0, B, A, C);

// label vertices
label("A", A, S);
label("B", B, S);
label("C", C, E);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this excellent idea. I very much enjoyed this Asymptote syntax. I will learn more about it.